# rails assign variable value to param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to assign the param 'starts_at' value to the @schedule_item variable, using the following code:

```
    @schedule_item = ScheduleItem.new
    @schedule_item.schedule = @schedule

    if params[:starts_at].present?
      @schedule_item.starts_at = params[:starts_at]
    end
```

However, when I place a binding.pry after the if statement, I see @schedule_item.starts_at is still nil. I also know that 'params[:starts_at]' returns => "01/17/2017 12:00 AM". Any thoughts?

Comment: it is whitelisted in your allowed params?

Comment: yep: params.require(:schedule_item).permit(:schedule_id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :page_id)

Comment: In the binding.pry I even try [at]schedule_item.starts_at = 1 which returns 1, but when I try [at]schedule_item.inspect I get : "#<ScheduleItem id: nil, schedule_id: 6, starts_at: nil, ends_at: nil, page_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, page_title: nil>"

Comment: anyone????????????

Comment: what is the data type for `starts_at` column in the database schema and which database are you using?

Comment: `starts_at` is date/time type or text type?

Comment: ahh it's datetime: t.datetime :starts_at, null: false

Comment: I've tried converting to datetime using: @schedule_item.starts_at = params[:starts_at].to_datetime but get the message: invalid date. Any ideas?

Comment: @jj1111 Check the date format of that input. It might not be the same as the one you need

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the value from a request param in a timestamp column in the database then you might want to parse it into a time value first.

```
foo = Time.parse( "1989-02-14" )
```

That should get you a time value - but you might want to validate it is in a range that makes sense before you store it